# What is the value of the angle x in the given figure? (by geometry)

Tags: geometry

For reference: In the figure, AOB is a quadrant and the quadrilaterals OMNL and LTQK are square.

[image]

My progress..I would like a solution by geometry...by trigonometry it is solved:
$\triangle QOL: \frac{r}{\sin45}=\frac{r\sqrt2}{2\sin 2\theta} \implies \sin2\theta =\frac{1}{2} \therefore \theta = 15^\circ$

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip squares vertically.

[image]

$\angle BDC=\angle BEC=x$ (angles of same segment)
 $\triangle BFE$ and $\triangle BGA$ are congruent.
Therefore, $\angle BEF=\angle BAG=x$
$\angle CAG=45^\circ=2x+x$ 
$\implies  x=15^\circ$